# Matlab: the meaning of '../' in a folder path

Tags: matlab

I stumble across some MATLAB codes about data file paths, something like:

```
data=csvread(sprintf('../data/cdflevel%dtable.csv',cdflevels(i)));
```

I am not sure what `'../'` does. Anyone can explain it?

Answer (score 1):

`../` moves one folder up from the current directory, before then changing to the `data` directory in the parent folder. It's not specific to MATLAB, just a [standard way of navigating a file system](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000795.htm).